# I can't find why my C code is not compiling and the other is running both are nearly same

Tags: arrays, string, pointers

I can't understand why one code is not working. I somehow managed to make it work by making some changes to it but but now I can't understand what the problem was. please help.

**This one is not running:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  char *name;
  int length;
  char *cptr = name;               //this line is different
  name = "DELHI";                  //This line is different
  printf ("%s\n", name);
  while(*cptr != '\0')
  {
    printf("%c is stored at address %u\n", *cptr, cptr);
    cptr++;
  }
  length = cptr - name;
  printf("\nLength of the string = %d\n", length);
}
```

**This one is running:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
  char *name;
  int length;
  char *cptr;
  name = ("DELHI");
  printf("%s\n",&name);
  cptr = name;
  while (*cptr != '\0') 
  {
    printf("%c is stored at address %u\n", *cptr, cptr);
    cptr++;
  }
  length = cptr-name;
  printf("\nLength of String = %d\n", length);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly; it'll be a lot easier to help.

Comment: It's only fair for you to provide the compiler errors along with your code sample, if it is not compiling.  Also compilers are usually pretty good at telling you what's wrong.  For example, mine tells me that you declared `main` wrong (should return int), you assigned a const char* to a char*, (writable strings), and you used a `%u` format specifier when you should have used `%p`.

Comment: sorry I am new here didn't knew

Answer (score 0):

In your first program:

```
char *name;
int length;
char *cptr = name;               //this line is different
```

Here, `name` is uninitialized, and you copy that uninitialized value into `cptr`. This causes undefined behaviour (along with later where you make actual use of `cptr`).

In your second program:

```
char *cptr;
name = ("DELHI");
printf("%s\n",&name);
cptr = name;
```

`name` is initialized, so when you copy that value into `cptr`, everything is good to go. Unfortunately, your `printf` line here is wrong - I'm not sure how your program is working; maybe just getting lucky. You want:

```
printf("%s\n", name);
```

Your programs both cause undefined behaviour when printing the value of `cptr` in your loop. Correct that print statement to use the matching format specifier for a pointer value:

```
printf("%c is stored at address %p\n", *cptr, (void *)cptr);
```